# Phoca Gallery Category List Customization

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am using PhocaGallery 3.2.6 on Joomla 2.5.6. On my Website, I have a long menu (Basically a Category Listing, comprising of Category Names) at the left side. I want to customize that.

Which PHP file I need to make changes to?

One module which actually shows the category list, has the following line ::

```
{phocagallery view=categories}
```

com_phocagallery/views/category/tmpl/default.php has the main content [thumbnail pictures etc], but for the left bar (showing category lists) I could not find the correct PHP file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to it, I just needed to modify the category links to point to some other resources on my site. These resources could be some PDFs, or Other special Images etc.

I had to add my custom code to the file /public_html/plugins/content/phocagallery/phocalgallery.php

There, I just changed the "href" properties of all anchors.